# For an uncountable set $I$, is every Borel set of $2^I$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $I$ be an uncountable set.
Consider $2^I$ to be a measure space with the usual coin-tossing measure.

That is, we define a measure on $2^I$ as follows.
First we define $\mu(N_p) = 2^{-|p|}$, where $N_p = \{ f \in 2^I : p \subset f \}$ for $p$ a finite partial function from $I$ to $2$.
Secondly, we extend the $\mu$ to a measure on clopen sets of $2^I$.
Thirdly, by the Carathéodory's extension theorem, we extend this measure to a measure on Baire sets of $2^I$.
Here, a Baire set means a set belongs the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the clopen sets.
Finally, we take the completion of this measure.

We write this complete measure space as $(2^I, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$.

My question is whether every Borel set of $2^I$ belongs to $\mathcal{A}$.

If $I$ were countable, this question would be obviously true since every Borel set is Baire set.
But $I$ is uncountable.
So there is a Borel set which is not a Baire set. For instance, singletons of $2^I$.

If there were a counterexample, we could take such a set as a open set.
So we can paraphrase the question whether every open set of $2^I$ belongs to $\mathcal{A}$.